# .NET Entity Framework: get entities from db having only its type

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How can I get entities from EF context when I only know its type?

I can do this:

```
db.Products.ToList();
```

To get all products from db. But how can I do it if I have `Product` type in a variable?

For example, if p is some object:

```
Type type = p.DeclaringType;   //get the type of the object (for example, Product)
```

And now how to get all entities of that type (which is a `DbSet` in EF context) from database?

MORE INFO:
Some of my models have one or more properties decorated with a specific attribute (for example, lets say Product.name and Customer.someproperty are decorated with that attribute).
What I want to do is, get all entities from those models from the dbcontext (in this case, it would be all products and all customers).
I have managed to obtain a List that contains all those properties (so in this case, it contains propertyInfo objects for  Product.name and Customer.someproperty)... but no idea how to get now all those entities from db...

Comment: That's almost always a smell - you're trying to "generalize" an already generic class like DbContext. Or trying to convert the simple objects used by EF to some complex "entity" type. A DbSet is a *repository* class that contains the mapping between your entity type and the underlying table. While you can use the [Set<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-6.0) method, you typically *don't* need to. In any case you'll have to configure that DbSet when creating the DbContext. That's why there's no `Set(Type)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I have  added some info explaining what I want to achieve and why...